# how do I get Position sticky to work for nav-bar for a web-page?

Tags: html, css

[Here is the CSS code. No matter what I do I could not get the nav-bar to stick at the top of the page when I scroll up. A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FZ52.png)

I tried removing the overflow:hidden property for the parent element and make sure my browser(chrome) is set to the latest version. None of them fixed the issue.

Comment: Please share the CSS code and the HTML in text. Post it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edit your question and please add the html code and the css that you have tried so far as a snippet for us to help you out.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For the `sticky` to work on the `navigation`, there has be content below it, also, we must give it a `top` value (from where the stickiness has to begin from).

The `overflow: hidden` hasn't got much to do with it.

This is how simple it is:

```css
#navigation {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/*extra styling for demonstration purpose only*/

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #daa500;
  border: 1px solid #daa500;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #daa500;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #daa500;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#navigation {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!--------Navigation  bar--------->
<section id="navigation">
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
<section id="content">
  <p id="header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Erat imperdiet
    sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat
    id. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium. Consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat.
  </p>
  <p id="about">
    Egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa. Dui sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed. Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus
    mauris a diam. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi
    morbi. Commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Scelerisque purus semper eget duis. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium
    vulputate. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea.
  </p>
  <p id="projects">
    Eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Enim tortor at auctor urna nunc. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Eget nullam non nisi
    est. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Varius quam quisque id diam vel quam. Nunc congue nisi
    vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget.
  </p>
  <p id="contact">
    Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum. Nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id. Facilisi etiam dignissim
    diam quis. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Egestas sed tempus urna et. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum
    est ultricies integer quis. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Tincidunt
    id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Convallis a cras semper auctor. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Cursus euismod quis viverra
    nibh. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id.
  </p>
  <!-- some more dummy text for demonstration -->
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed. Nulla facilisi nullam vehicula
    ipsum a arcu cursus. Amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis
    egestas. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Et tortor at risus viverra. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. Volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa. Lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum
    posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim. Scelerisque purus semper eget
    duis at. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque.
    Tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id.
    Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque
    viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus.
    Sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed.
    Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Sociis natoque
    penatibus et magnis dis. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Ultricies integer
    quis auctor elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Semper quis lectus nulla at. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus
    sed. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu.
  </p>
</section>
```

For demonstration purpose I added some dummy text (lorem ipsum).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it still not working for me, FYI my navigation bar comes after my header which takes up 100vw and 100vh. could this be the issue?

Comment: It's an open question for why you've set those values. Usually, to filter out the error causing issue, I start with the working example, and afterwards I construct on that. You should also provide some code for reproduction, for us to better help you.