# Linking to a specific section of another page is NOT working (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is my problem: I want to create a “back” link to the Specific section of my index.html when the user click on a project.

On my index.html I have all my sections and I have named each section with an ID. On the homepage

It doesn’t work: it returns to the homepage instead of the portfolio section… I would appreciate some help and advice because I am stuck at this point
Thank you in advance,

On my index.html I have named each section with an ID. On the homepage for E.G

```
<section id="portfolio " class="mt-3" >
```

On the Other page I create a “back” link to the portfolio section of my index.html

```
<a class="nav-link" href="../#portfolio ">
                    <span>portfolio </span></a>
            </li>
```

It doesn’t work: it returns to the homepage instead of the portfolio section…

It work fine on the same page  but not work other pages

it returns to the homepage instead of the portfolio section… I would appreciate some help and advice because I am stuck at this point
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75906421/2817442

Comment: Try `href="../index.html#portfolio"` It may make a difference..

Answer (score 1):

To create a "back" link that takes the user to a specific section of your `index.html` page, you can use HTML anchors and the `href` attribute. Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Assign an ID to the target section: In your `index.html` file, locate the section you want to link to (in this case, the portfolio section) and assign it a unique ID. For example:

```html
<section id="portfolio">
  <!-- Content of the portfolio section -->
</section>
```

2. Create a "back" link: In the section where you want to create the link that takes the user back to the portfolio section, add an anchor tag (`<a>`) with the `href` attribute set to `#portfolio`. For example:

```html
<a href="#portfolio">Back to Portfolio</a>
```

3. Testing: Save your `index.html` file and open it in a web browser. Clicking on the "Back to Portfolio" link should now scroll the page to the portfolio section.

Make sure that the IDs you assign to sections are unique and match the target section ID in the `href` attribute of the link. Also, ensure that the link is placed in the appropriate location in your HTML structure.

Comment: It works fine it has the same page what if I have another page back and I want to back to the home page on a specific section It doesn't work it returns me to the homepage instead of the portfolio section…

Comment: @MuhammadRiaz You’re in control. What you put in your code is what you’ll see as a result. may I suggest that you take another look, and maybe you’ll see that it actually is setup to go to home, and that all you need to do is to change one line of code regarding where the link will eventually go to.

Comment: Dženis H. - You have several recent answers here that appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

In section link write this code:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"></a>
```